# Flash AS3: How Do I Change the Z-index of a Constructed Graphic?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, z-index, waveform

I'm trying to make a program that pulses to the beat of a song, with a wave pattern on top, but the wave pattern seems to be behind everything. I know how to change the index of a child added to the stage, but I have no clue on how to set the index value of a graphic. Here's my code(if relevant):

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.text.TextField;

var snd:Sound = new Sound();
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("SuperHexagonMusic.mp3");
var channel:SoundChannel;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, everyFrame);

snd.load(req);
channel = snd.play();
channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onPlaybackComplete);

function everyFrame(event:Event):void
{
    pulse.alpha = channel.leftPeak * 3;
    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    const PLOT_HEIGHT:int = 200;
    const CHANNEL_LENGTH:int = 256;

    SoundMixer.computeSpectrum(bytes, false, 0);

    var g:Graphics = this.graphics;

    g.clear();

    g.lineStyle(0, 0x000000);
    g.beginFill(0x000000);
    g.moveTo(0, PLOT_HEIGHT);

    var n:Number = 0;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < CHANNEL_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        n = (bytes.readFloat() * PLOT_HEIGHT);
        g.lineTo(i * 2.5, PLOT_HEIGHT - n);
    }

    g.lineTo(CHANNEL_LENGTH * 2.5, PLOT_HEIGHT);
    g.endFill();

    g.lineStyle(0, 0xFFFFFF);
    g.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 0.5);
    g.moveTo(CHANNEL_LENGTH * 2.5, PLOT_HEIGHT);

    for (i = CHANNEL_LENGTH; i > 0; i--)
    {
        n = (bytes.readFloat() * PLOT_HEIGHT);
        g.lineTo(i * 2.5, PLOT_HEIGHT - n);
    }  

    g.lineTo(0, PLOT_HEIGHT);
    g.endFill();
}

function onPlaybackComplete(event:Event):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, everyFrame);
}
```

What I'm hoping for is the constructed wave pattern to be on top of the pulse, but the current code produces this result:

[image]

In the image, you can see the end of the wave pattern poking out behind the pulse.

So in short: How might I bring that wave pattern to the front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent's `Graphics` is always behind all parent's children. You should make yourself another `Sprite` or `Shape` object, place it on top of your display list, and draw on its graphics instead.

```
var spectrum:Shape=new Shape();
addChild(spectrum); // if last added, will be on top
function everyFrame(e:Event):void {
     var g:Graphics=spectrum.graphics; // that's all you need to change!
     // the rest of code follows
}
```